# visual studio c++ empty string pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012, string

I have written some code with string pointers in VS2013 c++, as follows:

```
      public struct MyStruct
          {  // some declarations
             string *MyStrAr[6];
          };
          // ... some more code
      MyStruct *AStructNode = new MyStruct;
```

the user gives input that initialises some strands of the Mystringarray and assigns a value to them. Further in the program, I want to check if `Mystringarray[i]` has been initialised. I have tried the following:

```
if (AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]==NULL)
if (AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]->empty())
if(*(AStructNode->MyStrAr[i])="")
if (AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]->_Mysize==);
```

the first doesnt capture anything (whether the string is populated or not), the rest throw an exception about trying to access protected memory.
 I have also tried `try { } catch(...)`{}, also unsuccessfully. Have read as many posts on the matter before posting this, I am amateur programmer, any help/direction appreciated. (I realise, I can sidestep the issue by, for example, declaring an array of strings rather than pointers, but I'd rather understand why, and if my oversight is very elementary, so be it!). If of any help, the debugger usually throws the exception on a line of the xstring.cpp, where it says something like 
`return (this->_Mysize == 0);` Cheers, Niko

Comment: It is not clear what language you are using. Whether it is C++ and there is a typo in your code or it is C++/CLI

Comment: Trying to read invalid memory does not throw an exception. so your try catch block is no help here. You'd need to allocate the string pointers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am not sure which version I am using, I guess its c++/cli. How could i find out for sure?

Comment: Either you select CLR console application or win32 console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]==NULL
```

You have not initizlized MyStrAr[i] so it might not be NULL.

```
AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]->empty()
```

Dereferencing uninitialized pointer has undefined behaviour.

```
*(AStructNode->MyStrAr[i])=""
```

Same as above. Comparing to const char* literal (I'm assuming you don't actually mean to use assignement) won't work either.

```
AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]->_Mysize==
```

Same as the above two.

You cannot test if value is uninitialized. In fact you shouldn't read such memory at all. Initialize your values with say, NULL. Then your first test `AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]==NULL` should work as long as `i <= 5`. For the other tests to work, you would need to construct the strings pointed by `MyStrAr` too because dereferencing a `NULL` pointer has undefined behaviour.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    string *MyStrAr[6] = {NULL};
};
```

If your compiler does not support brace initialization, you need to use a constructor:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    string *MyStrAr[6];

    MyStruct(): MyStrAr() {}
};
```

A sidenote: Does MyStrAr absolutely must be a c style array? `std::array` has many advantages. `std::vector` is good too if your compiler does not support c++11.

Comment: good idea; tried it but got a compile error; "cannot specify explicit initialiser in arrays". But I suppose i can write a small function to do that. Will let you know if it worked...

Comment: it did...spent lots of time trying to solve this, so many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

the parameter _Mysize is private for the String class so you dont have permission to use that!
try this instead:

if (AStructNode->MyStrAr[i]->size()==...(some number));